# javascript undefined label from inside function

Tags: javascript, break

I am trying to essentially 'pause' code until something becomes true and continue execution. This throws an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Undefined label 'breakme'

After 'breakme' I would like to code to execute further. I don't want to call function something again. Is this not possible to do it in such way?

```
function something(){
  // more code
  var condition;
  breakme: if (!condition) {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      // if (condition) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      break breakme; //continue with more code 2
      // }
    }, 100);
    return;
  }
  // more code 2
}
```

Comment: You can’t refer to `breakme` in its own definition.

Comment: You can use generator OR you can return a function which wraps your `// more code2` and call the function upon condition meeting your need. The code you wrote is not valid because function is not an object.

Comment: Using an interval feels kind of ugly... This is not the way you do async in JavaScript. Can't you use promises or at least callbacks?

Comment: @sjahan what can go wrong with interval in such case?

Comment: @Toniq it's not it can go wrong. It is just not very elegant, it's basically like doing `while(!condition) {}` to synchronize async code, it is active waiting. The elegant way to do this would be that fetching the `condition` would return a Promise, that way, you could synchronize the code nicely and efficiently. Question is: what made `condition` value to change? This part of the code is probably wrong or badly used. If you want a callback or a Promise example, I can post you one, just ask me back to this comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below. It runs your code 1 block and then defers execution of code 2 block until you call it again.

```
function something(){
  // more code
  return function() {
    // more code 2
  }
}

var x = something();

if(!condition) x();
```